# Uploading codeigniter site from local server to live

Tags: php, codeigniter, web-hosting

Hy every one, I made a site in codeigniter and its working fine on local server. I uploaded on live server: domain name (http://fantastictravels.co/) and it says "This fantastictravels.co page can’t be found"

I tried many different things but its not working. Here is my code of of view and controller:

controller:

```
<?php

class Travels extends CI_Controller {

     function __construct(){
        parent :: __construct();
        $this->load->model('travel');
    }

    public function index()
    {

        $this->load->view('index');
    }
}
```

View:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us">
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
   </head>
<body>

    <div class="content">

       This is test
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In my config file, the base_url is "http://fantastictravels.co/" and my all the files are located at the root directory of "http://fantastictravels.co/".
Help me out please.

Comment: add image of host file system too

Comment: your .htaccess file?

Comment: Have you followed the style guide? http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Comment: Anything in `.htaccess` file?

Comment: It is working with index.php i.e. `http://fantastictravels.co/index.php/travels/search_travel`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my controller and model file name was in lowercase letter which I changed into uppercase and it became fixed... :)

Answer (score 0):

1st, do you have a **view file** named index.php?
Are your view files in the view folder?

Put this in your .htaccess file

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|  (.*)\.swf|forums|images|css|downloads|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

Go to your config file, and make sure this line looks like this

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```